# Error appending Pagedown in AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, markdown, pagedown

Based on this question, though I felt this warranted its own question: [Google pagedown AngularJS directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908748/google-pagedown-angularjs-directive)

Following the example from this question, it seems to work, however I am running into issues when I try to append a directive to the page.

Here is the code I have in the linking function:

```
  scope.editor_id = null;

  if(attrs.id == null) {
    scope.editor_id = nextID++;
  } else {
    scope.editor_id = attrs.id;
  }

  //append editor HTML
  //has to be done here so that it is available to the editor when it is run below
  var editor_html = $compile(
      '<div id="wmd-button-bar-' + scope.editor_id + '"></div>' +
      '<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + scope.editor_id + '" ng-model="content"></textarea>'
  )(scope);


  element.find('.wmd-panel').append(editor_html);


  var editor = new Markdown.Editor(editor_converter, "-" + scope.editor_id);
  editor.run();
```

However, when I append one of these to the document, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null
```

This error tends to crop up when the `wmd-input` is not present in the HTML. however, I am adding it with the `$compile` function, and it works on page load, but not when it is appended. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

#### UPDATE

I was able to reproduce your problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/R2eDKBreHmYBjPtU0JxD?p=preview

#### Why `typeError: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null`?

- I was wrong with my previous assumption ( the composite linking function do returns the element)
- The problem is with the way you use `angular.element#find`.
- `angular.element#find` only search for child elements not on the whole document.
- the DOM element with a `.wmd-panel` class is not a child of the current element.

#### This should work fine:

```
angular.element('.wmd-panel').append(editor_html);
```

Comment: I'd like only to note that you need to be careful when adding node not to the child element - if the directive's parent node/scope will be destroyed (with ng-if or by routing) this `editor_html` will not and will keep the link to the directive's scope. That may lead to memory leaks.

Comment: @GRaAL you are correct. I only answered the OP why the error occurs and how to fix it. It also feels "non angular" to use selectors on the document like that. I bet there is more angular way to achieve what he needs but the question doesn't provide much details.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing compile like this:

```
$compile('template stuff goes here')(scope, function(cloned, scope){
   element.append(cloned); 
});
```

You may also have to define your editor inside the callback function because I'm not sure if it's asynchronous or not. You may also want to re-consider having your directive compile and append to itself like this. Why not just add more instances of the entire directive using something like ng-repeat?

Also, if you have multiple instances inside this one directive, you will lose reference to editor. Not sure what's going on outside this code so I can't really tell.

Comment: The linking function is not async