# Modify Markdown ng-repeat directive to support tabset from angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, markdown

I've attempted to modify the directive here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20957476/149060 So that each ng-repeat item will display inside a tabset the editor and it's preview each on a tab.  The intent is to have the items work like GitHub comment boxes:

[image]

I've added Angular-UI dependencies and amended the markup, but it's not working, here: http://cssdeck.com/labs/moccmuta

Comment: the link you provided is without angular-ui

Comment: Sorry, I seem to not have saved my changes.  Will re-edit the code and post updated when link is valid.

Comment: @IlanFrumer I've updated the link with the saved changes

Comment: It looks like `tabset` directive deffer the creation of the editor so it's not available yet. I will take a different approach here, buy only tomorrow...